# Add custom html to lightbox2

Tags: javascript, lightbox2

I have a gallery made with lightbox 2 made in a normal matter with thumbnails etc. Now I need to add some HTML via JS into a div of lightbox 2. How do I do  that?

First I thought, just do a function and call it with onclick, but lightbox isn't ready then, so I have to wait for it to be ready, how do I do that? Lightbox uses the prototype framework. Is it possible in this way, something like a listener?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lightbox2 doesn't have any public event for that. Your best bet is to use a script that has public events that you can subscribe to. I would recommend either [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) or [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/).

With Fancybox you would just need to add the code inside the `onComplete` function that is called when the Fancybox is finished opening.

*Note that both of these use jQuery, but that shouldn't be a problem as long as you use [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).*